# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error : "com.mycompany.myappname" has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlment

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I set the entitlements file correctly.
I'm getting the cloud url.

the error happen after im trying to save values in the keyValue store.
I can write and read from the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore,
But after the method finished, I got the error I wrote in the title of the question.

this error happen on ipad 1,
when compiling the same project to the iphone, it works ok without error.

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you download your app from the AppStore and update it using XCode.

Have a look at the "Recommended Testing Procedure" in [Technote 2285](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2285/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011323)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using different targets for iPhone and iPad versions of your app? Check your entitlements file and make sure it has the correct values for organization all targets.

You might also want to do a text search in your projects folder and see if any files contain the line "com.mycompany.myappname".